# How to learn GIS?

Tags: references

Could someone guide me where to study all about GIS and pursue it as a profession without going to college?

I am seeking links.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: The "without going to college" part makes this tricky. There's hundreds to thousands of hours of training and practice to make GIS a *profession*. Those late nights in the cartography and computer labs set the stage for my professional development; I can't imagine a different route. While most of the job postings I've seen allow for "or equivalent" there are few equivalents to a "4-year degree in geography, biology, forestry or related field".